# How to calculate hamming score for multilabel classification

Tags: python, python-3.x, multilabel-classification

I tried to calculate hamming loss and hamming score for multilabel text classification

```
def hamming_score(y_true, y_pred, normalize=True, sample_weight=None):
    acc_list = []
    for i in range(y_true.shape[0]):
        set_true = set( np.where(y_true[i])[0] )
        set_pred = set( np.where(y_pred[i])[0] )
        tmp_a = None
        if len(set_true) == 0 and len(set_pred) == 0:
        tmp_a = 1
        else:
            tmp_a = len(set_true.intersection(set_pred))/float(len(set_true.union(set_pred)))
        acc_list.append(tmp_a)
    return np.mean(acc_list)

def print_score(y_pred, clf):
    print("Clf: ", clf.__class__.__name__)
    print("Hamming loss: {}".format(hamming_loss(y_pred, y_test)))
    print("Hamming score: {}".format(hamming_score(y_pred, y_test)))
    print("---")   

nb_clf = MultinomialNB()
sgd = SGDClassifier(loss='hinge', penalty='l2', alpha=1e-3, random_state=42, max_iter=6, tol=None)
lr = LogisticRegression()
mn = MultinomialNB()

for classifier in [nb_clf, sgd, lr, mn]:
    clf = OneVsRestClassifier(classifier)
    clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
    y_pred = clf.predict(x_test)
    print_score(y_pred, classifier)
```

The result of hamming loss is occur but the hamming score get error, can anyone help me fix this? thank you

> Clf:  MultinomialNB
>       Hamming loss: 0.01911111111111111
>       ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
>       ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
>        in 
>             8     clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
>             9     y_pred = clf.predict(x_test)
>       ---> 10     print_score(y_pred, classifier)
>
> ```
> <ipython-input-313-60ed43baa4c1> in print_score(y_pred, clf)
>      21     print("Clf: ", clf.__class__.__name__)
>      22     print("Hamming loss: {}".format(hamming_loss(y_pred, y_test)))
> ---> 23     print("Hamming score: {}".format(hamming_score(predictions, y_test)))
>      24     print("---")
>
> <ipython-input-313-60ed43baa4c1> in hamming_score(y_true, y_pred, normalize, sample_weight)
>       8     acc_list = []
>       9     for i in range(y_true.shape[0]):
> ---> 10         set_true = set( np.where(y_true[i])[0] )
>      11         set_pred = set( np.where(y_pred[i])[0] )
>      12         tmp_a = None
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py in __bool__(self)
>     285             return self.nnz != 0
>     286         else:
> --> 287             raise ValueError("The truth value of an array with more than one "
>     288                              "element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().")
>     289     __nonzero__ = __bool__
>
> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().
> ```

Comment: What are you using `numpy.where` for there?

Answer (score 0):

Hi could you try out below code and see if it's working or not

```
  print("Hamming score: {}".format(hamming_score(y_pred, y_test,normalize=False)))
```